# Calculating the voltage at Node A

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I need to calculate the voltage at node A at the below circuit. Please tell me whether my approach is right

[image]

So, I am assuming that the 1000ohms in series with the voltage sources as internal resistances.

Current through the 500ohm would be, I = 10/500 = 20mA

But we need to consider the internal resistance of 1000ohms right
So, terminal voltage, Er = V - IR, Er = 10 - (20mA)*(1000Ohms) = 10-20 = -10V ?

What am i doing wrong here?

Please let me know

Comment: If you redraw the circuit with the two 1k resistors on the right in series with the 0.5k resistor you can easily see the voltage divider described by Tabin1000, and the solution is trivial.

Comment: By symmetry, the same value of current flows through each 1k resistor. Let this current be \$I\$. Then solve using KVL, for example, on one of the meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an voltage divider.
When you have two 1000 ohm resistors in parallel like this, then it equals one 10V source with 500 ohm resistor in series with it.
When you make voltage divider with two resistors of the same value, then you divide the voltage by 2.

10V / 2 = 5V

**It means that on point A you will get 5V.**

Comment: I am still unable to get when you say, " When you have two 1000 ohm resistors in parallel like this, then it equals one 10V source with 500 ohm resistor in series with it". I can do it in KCL and KVL. But is there an intuitive way of understanding this

Comment: If you have x equal resistors in parralel then resistance = R / x

Comment: But the point is I have a Voltage source in parallel too.. What to do about that voltage source. Please, excuse me for asking naive questions. I am a beginner and would like to understand the answer in simple and intuitive terms for strong basics

Comment: If you have 2 voltage sources with common ground and the same voltage like that then it works as one source.

Comment: So, it wont matter even if one of the source is absent, I would still get 5V at node A? Is this correct? Any analogy or intuitive explanation you can provide? It would be really helpful to me.

Comment: You would need to still have the 2 resistors in parralel but both resistors will be connected to one source.

Comment: You should still get 5V at node A

Comment: There is schematic of new circuit: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B9ndDBy2HIjwa7sdMcjGnJSefI8l0n56/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thank you @Tabin1000 . It is clear that the voltage is 5V at Node A when you re-draw the circuit like the one which you showed. Just couldn't understand that the other voltage source won't play any role